# java: perform set, setbit, get and getbit in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

***Edited***

I am trying to implement the following functions in my program using hashmap.

- get
- getBit
- set
- setBit

Here is the code.

```
static HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public static String dictGet(String key){
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    return val;
}

public static int dictGet(String key, int pos){ 
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    byte[] bytes = val.getBytes(); 
    byte byt = bytes[pos /8];
    System.out.println("Byte : "+byt); 
    return (byt >> (pos % 8) ) & 1;

}
public static void dictSet(String key, String val){
    hashmap.put(key, val);
}
public static void dictSet(String key, int pos, byte bitval){
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    byte[] bytes = val.getBytes();
    byte byt = bytes[pos /8];

    if(bitval == 1){
        bytes[pos /8] = (byte) (bytes[pos /8]| (1 << (pos % 8)));
    }
    else if(bitval == 0){
        bytes[pos /8] = (byte) (bytes[pos /8] & ~(1 << (pos % 8)));
    }

    hashmap.put(key, new String(bytes));
}
```

I want to achieve *O(1)* complexity for each of these functions. But currently `getBit()` and `setBit()` functions are taking O(n) time complexity.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code? And why do you use a String to hold bytes. Why don't you use a byte array instead? A String is a sequence of characters, not bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very inefficient. `val.getBytes()` will allocate new array (actually more than one) and encode whole string into it every time you call it. This is likely going to be the most expensive operation in this snippet.

Moreover, this code mixes two completely different representations. To make your intentions clear and avoid mistakes, you should stick to one. If you want to operate on bytes, store `byte[]` in your hash map. If you want to operate on characters or code points use [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) or [codePointAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)). If you need to convert between those representation, do it once during initialization.

Notice also, that [getBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) encodes the string using platform's default charset. This, most likely, is not what you want and your code will break, if UTF-16 is used.

Here is an example using `StringBuilder`, Note that in Java `char` has 16 bits and this code uses that full range:

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

      Map<String, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();

      void setBit(final String key, final int n) {
          final StringBuilder s = this.map.get(key);
          final char c = s.charAt(n / 16);
          s.setCharAt(n / 16, (char) (c | 1 << n % 16));
      }

      int getBit(final String key, final int n) {
          final StringBuilder s = this.map.get(key);
          final int c = s.charAt(n / 16);
          return (c << n % 16 & 0x8000) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
      }

      CharSequence getValue(final String key) {
          return this.map.get(key);
      }

      public static void main(final String[] args) {
          final Test t = new Test();
          t.map.put("x", new StringBuilder("abc"));
          t.map.put("y", new StringBuilder("abc"));
          t.setBit("x", 3);
          t.setBit("y", 4);

          // many methods accept any CharSequence not just String
          final CharSequence xValue = t.getValue("x");
          final CharSequence yValue = t.getValue("y");
          System.out.println(String.join(",", xValue, yValue));
      }
}
```

Comment: what will be the complexity for creating a string object from a byte array if I stored byte array into hash map?

Comment: @AthulSukumaran once again: why do you want to create a String from an array of bytes that seem completely arbitrary binary data? Stick to byte[] to represent binary data. Don't use String. Or at least explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AthulSukumaran roughly the same as creating byte array from String. Strings are immutable. If you want to change them in O(1) use `StringBuilder` or `byte[]`. In a lot of places where you need a `String`, `CharSequence` is enough.

Comment: So you mean to say byte[] helps me achieve O(1) complexity for getting hashmap value as string as well as setting bit of value.? @Banthar

Comment: That doesn't explain why. You can't convert an arbitrary sequence of bytes into a String. That doesn't make sense. Explain why you would want to do that.

Comment: @AthulSukumaran No. If you want to change the value of a `String` you need to copy it - which is `O(n)`. If you want to avoid the copy, you need to replace `String` with mutable structure (`byte[]`, `StringBuilder`) everywhere that value is used.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? I am not familiar with StringBuilder@Banthar

Comment: @AthulSukumaran There is no way to do it. Either you accept the cost of creating a String or use a different data structure.

Comment: Can you explain the data structure? @Banthar

Comment: @AthulSukumaran different data structure like `StringBuilder` or `byte[]` see my answer for example.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expliain these lines? `s.setCharAt(n / 16, (char) (c | 1 << n % 16));` and `return (c << n % 16 & 0x8000) != 0 ? 1 : 0;` ?@Banthar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126991/discussion-between-athul-sukumaran-and-banthar).

Answer (score 2):

No, the complexity of this is not O(1), it is O(n), where `n` is the length of the string. The reason for this is that `bytes` that you receive from `getBytes()` must always be a *copy*; otherwise, `String`'s immutability would be compromised.

This can be confirmed by looking at the source code: `getBytes` calls `encode`, which calls `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
static byte[] encode(Charset cs, char[] ca, int off, int len) {
    StringEncoder se = new StringEncoder(cs, cs.name());
    char[] c = Arrays.copyOf(ca, ca.length); // <<=== Copying an array is O(n)
    return se.encode(c, off, len);
}
```

To get O(1) amortized complexity (assuming that you are going to access most bits of a string) you would need additional storage - a `HashMap<String,byte[]>` which would be a "parallel map" to the original hash map, storing "cached" values of `getBytes()` calls. Start by looking for a cached representation; if it is not there, go for the actual value, call `getBytes()`, and cache the result. The rest of the code would remain the same.

```
byte[] bytes = cache.get(key);
if (bytes == null) {
    String val = (String) hashmap.get(key);
    bytes = val.getBytes();
    cache.put(key, bytes);
}
byte byt = bytes[pos /8];
System.out.println("Byte : "+byt); 
return (byt >> (pos % 8) ) & 1;
```

Note that the maintenance of `cache` is on you: each time that you modify `hashmap` you need to remove the corresponding key from the `cache`.

Comment: But again to store byte[] in hashmap, again I need to perform getBytes() operation. Right?

Comment: @AthulSukumaran Right. However, you'd perform it once per string, so if you need to get most bits from a string, the amortized cost would be O(1), because the first call will "pay" for the remaining 8*n-1 calls. For example, let's say you have a ten-byte string, and you want to get all its 80 bits. You will make 80 calls, one of which will complete in O(10) and the rest will complete in O(1).

Comment: Yeah. That's fine. But is there any way to have O(1) for every call?

Comment: Here set value as String will always have high complexity for every new string. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I know this not related to your answer, but if you are using Java, you should be using generic types so that the cast is not required.

Coming to your answer, the complexity of String.getBytes() depends on the length of the String. Think in this way, the getBytes() method convert every character in the String to a byte. Hence, the complexity is O(L), where L is the length of the String.